# How should I approach decrypting packet protocols?

Tags: ida, packet

I'm able to see the packets before they're encrypted by setting a breakpoint before the encryption subroutine. My problem is that this subroutine is really complicated and goes really deep. Which steps should I follow in order to obtain this encryption function? Or rather to be able to decrypt this packet protocol?

Comment: Have you used signsrch to check if your program has some standard encryption algorithms linked in?

Comment: Now i did. Here's the result: http://i.imgur.com/GGjXa7Z.png

Comment: This is a good start - there are several encryption algorithms in your binary (AES (Rijndael), Windows Crypt, Blowfish, ...). Set hardware breakpoints on those data tables, and step over the encryption function. Or, check where these tables are used, and set normal breakpoints on the code that uses them. Or, look at the source code of open-source implementations of these, and compare the source with your subroutine.

Comment: I'm afraid i cannot find the address(003758f8 for ex.) for these tables in IDA.

Comment: This is because these are file offsets, and IDA label names are made from memory locations. But IDA shows the memory location and the file offset next to each other at the bottom of the IDA View (disassembly resp. graphical view), this should help you find them.

Comment: Thanks i was abled to set the breakpoint. When i set a hardware breakpoint on blowfish bfp table it stopped there.

Comment: Archlord 1, Lol I wrote a packet bot for that game years, years ago that helped me level a ton of accounts and collected gold for me and also sent all the good unique gears by mailbox to my master account quit that game though because it moved away from Codemasters. You never really have to understand how packet encryptions work that's why we got DLL injection just inject a dll that's listening on some port you set and control it via your own packet system I use telnet when I get started (yes you will run into problems if you wish to make clientless bot later on), I also sold HP Potions lowest

Comment: Well the game was shutdown few years ago so i'm planning to work on an emulator so i kinda need to understand what packets say :)